# ImportJSON for Google Scripts error: "TypeError: transformFunc is not a function"

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, import

I am trying to get a JSON file to a google spreadcheet.
The the API call is made and the JSON file is retrieved with the "ImportJSONAdvanced" function from  [ImportJSON bradjasper version 1.5](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs#L219).
But when it reaches line 422, it gives an error saying "TypeError: transformFunc is not a function".
These are the arguments I am passing:

```
const URL_query = 'URL1='+ myquery
const API_Call = {  
    headers: { 'method_for_key': 'my_apy_key' },
    json: true,
    gzip: true,
}
var parsedJSON = ImportJSONAdvanced(URL_query, API_Call)
```

Answer (score -1):

if you check [the source code](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs#L219-L221), you'll see that you are obviously missing some arguments to ImportJSONAdvanced. Specifically, the error message is complaining about missing the last argument, `transformFunc` but probably this is not the only error you will get.

Comment: No, it was the only error. I changed transformFunc = function () {} in the ImportJSONAdavanced,, and it passed the full JSON to my google sheet. Problem was that it passed the whole JSON file only to one single row.
Maybe I have to add some arguments to the transformFunc. Can you give me some hints on that?

Comment: please check the source code and ask if you have a specific question